# Regex elegant pattern match

Tags: regex

Can someone maybe help me with this regex? I am using Javascript and classic ASP.

```
checkxls = checkxls.match(/'.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?';/ig)
```

I need to match this pattern exactly.

I am looking for a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: a pattern match, I am importing an excel file into mysl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negative character class to avoid unnecessary backtracking:

```
/'[^']*'(?:, '[^']*'){13};/g
```

You can also drop the case-insensitive flags since there are no letters in your regular expression. This might give a small performance improvement.

Comment: Hi mark any idea how I would do the same thing but just look for this pattern?

('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'),

it is basically the same pattern but just with a starting bracket and closing bracket

Answer (score 3):

```
/('', ){13}'';/ig
```

Comment: checkxls.match(/('.*?', ){13}'.*?';/ig); <<< like this

Comment: You don't need the `//i` flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?:'[^']*', ){13}'[^']*';/g
```